# How to set up an event listener and remove it after first fired event using react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want' to set up an event listener to get **only the first** `touchstart` event on `window`. **Once that happens, I want to remove that listener.**

I'm using React Hooks.

**QUESTION**

I want to know if this is right, or if there's a better approach:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function onFirstTouch() {
      setWindowTouch(true);
      window.removeEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch, false);
    }
    window.addEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch);
  }, []);
```

It seems correct, but also feels that I'm going to set the listener again, when my component gets unmounted.

---

**NOTE:**

I know I could do something like this (use a "hasTouched" `ref` to check if the first event has already fired and ignore further events), but this is not exactly the same thing.

```
useEffect(() => {

    function handleTouch() {
      if (hasTouched.current === true) {
        return;
      }
      hasTouched.current = true;
      setWindowTouch(true);
    }

    window.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouch);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleTouch);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue I see is that you need to clean up the listener on unmount in case a touch never occurs, so that a touch after unmount doesn't try to act on your unmounted component.

So I would change it to the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function onFirstTouch() {
      // The order of these two lines shouldn't really matter, but I would
      // remove the listener before triggering a re-render via setWindowTouch
      window.removeEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch);
      setWindowTouch(true);
    }
    window.addEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch);
  }, []);
```

Regarding:

> feels that I'm going to set the listener again, when my component gets unmounted

The only thing that would be executed on unmount is the returned function (i.e. `() => window.removeEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch)`). It would only set the listener again if the component gets re-mounted.

Comment: I alway thought that if I was using and `empty dependency array [ ]`, my effect would run after 1st render and also after unmount. But from what you've pointed out, I'm understanding now that it will run after 1st render, and only the returned function will run after unmount, is that right? Just to clear things a bit more, what if I don't pass a return function (while still using the empty array `[ ]`)? Does it mean that my effect is going to run after 1st render and nothing will run after unmount? Is that also correct? Thanks!

Comment: Correct. When using an empty dependency array, the effect only executes once (on mount) and the cleanup only executes once (on unmount). If you don't specify a cleanup function, then nothing will run on unmount.

Comment: I've proposed a minor change to the documentation wording. Look at my change [here](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/pull/1990/files) and see if that would have helped avoid the confusion.

Comment: I think it helps a lot! That is exactly the line that caused my misunderstanding before. Thanks!